# Row inserted to DB in main app is not available in the different process. Can MySQL defer some queries?

Tags: mysql, queue

I have such problem. My main app process some request and insert the new row into DB, then send an Event to the queue. I have the different process that listens on that queue and when he get details about an inserted object and try to get it from DB, DB returns empty row. I wrote an algorithm with backoff and usually after 3 or 4 times, I manage to get that row. 
And my question is, are they some default caching mechanism in MySql that cause it.

I am using Laravel 5.0 as app framework, MySQL 5.6.38 as DB and

Comment: You’ve forgot to COMMIT

Comment: Can I commit a query without starting the transaction. I am thinking if locking the table on which I am executing insert query, would solve a problem with synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Use Innodb.

Do not use `LOCK TABLES`.

Do

```
BEGIN;
-- some SQL statements that need to be treated atomically:
INSERT INTO my_table ...;
INSERT INTO my_queue ...;
COMMIT;
```

By using `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, you can ignore the setting of `autocommit`, which *may* be tripping you up.

There *may* be some tricky business going on in the queue; please show us the SQL for enqueuing and dequeuing, pluse `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.